# equality of integrals implies two functions are equal

Tags: calculus, integration

If I have: 
$   \int_0^1 x^i P(x)\ dx=\int_0^1 x^i f(x) \ dx\ .   $

where $i$ is integer run from 0 to $n$. $P(x)$ is polynomial.

Can I conclude that $P(x)=f(x)$ ?
I guess this may happen provided $n$ larger than $deg(P(x)$ but still have no rigorous argument for it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions are fulfilled for $n=1$, $P(x)=1$ and $f(x)=-6x^2+6x$.

Comment: I love those counter examples...

Comment: In fact we have some moment conditions here. In some circumstances we could look at these integrals as the moments of certain measures. The equality of moments do not imply the measures are equal.

Comment: Yes, I realize for $n=1$, the formula is closely related to centroid

Answer (score 3):

Your hypothesis is equivalent to
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^{i} \bigl(P(x) - f(x)\bigr)\, dx = 0,\quad i = 0, \dots, n,
$$
which amounts to saying $P - f$ is orthogonal to the space of polynomials on $[0, 1]$ of degree at most $n$ with respect to the inner product on $L^{2}([0, 1])$.

Loosely, each condition reduces the dimension of the solution space by one. If $f$ ranges over an infinite-dimensional space (e.g., if $f$ is a polynomial of arbitrary degree, or if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function), then no, those conditions are not enough to deduce $P = f$.